# VB.NET FormStartPosition after resizing

Tags: vb.net, forms, events, location

I need to resize my form before showing it:

```
Private Sub frm1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Me.Width = Me.pnlMain.Width + 25

End Sub
```

During development, my form is really wide to show me some controls on the right side of the form. They are not visible at runtime, and my form should not be so wide as during development.

However, I would still like to use the form's "CenterScreen" startup position.

This does not work because VB.NET sets the form's location BEFORE the load event.

Can somebody help?

This did not work:

```
    InitializeComponent()

    Me.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen 'This is done BEFORE the load event, so it is too early for my purposes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Shown` event:

```
Private Sub MyForm_Shown(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
    Me.Location = New Point(CInt((Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width / 2) - (Me.Width / 2)), CInt((Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height / 2) - (Me.Height / 2)))
End Sub
```

EDIT: or better yet, the `HandleCreated` event, so you don't see the form quickly appear in its original place and them move to center screen:

```
Private Sub MyForm_HandleCreated(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.HandleCreated
    Me.Location = New Point(CInt((Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width / 2) - (Me.Width / 2)), CInt((Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height / 2) - (Me.Height / 2)))
End Sub
```

Comment: That would work, but I am looking for a way to use the Form's startup position, not a "hack".

Comment: @tmighty -- What's a hack is having controls on your form that the user isn't meant to see and resizing the form at load time.  What I'm suggesting is not a hack, it's a perfectly legitimate way to accomplish what you need.  In programming, as you know, there is always more than one way to get something done.

Comment: Well, okay, then just let me say that I don't want to have another hack :-)